# OpenSSH declares ssh-rsa deprecated. What do I do next?

Tags: ssh, key-management, openssh

With [the 8.2 release](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.2) of OpenSSH, they have declared that `ssh-rsa` for SHA-1 will soon be removed from the defaults:

> ## Future deprecation notice
>
> It is now possible<sup>[[1]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/014.pdf)</sup> to perform chosen-prefix attacks against the
> SHA-1 hash algorithm for less than USD$50K. For this reason, we will
> be disabling the `ssh-rsa` public key signature algorithm that depends
> on SHA-1 by default in a near-future release.
>
> This algorithm is unfortunately still used widely despite the
> existence of better alternatives, being the only remaining public key
> signature algorithm specified by the original SSH RFCs.

If I have (and might use, but not sure where) an `ssh-rsa` key, what are the next steps for me? Pretend I don't have another key yet.

So far, I've been supposing this process:

1. Generate new key(s).
2. Add new keys to *known* services.
3. [Rename the old key(s)](https://serverfault.com/a/727887/115583) so they are not automatically offered to remotes.

   - Then when I try a server that used to work, it will reject me and I'll swap it to the replacement key.
4. Anything else?

Comment: Hm. Maybe it's wise to mention SHA-1 in the title of this question? Or is that too much of a clue to the answer?

Comment: @AdamKatz As far as I knew at the time, _all_ `ssh-rsa` keys were SHA-1, since there are other RSA keys that explicitly mention their SHA algorithm. I suspect that people who are looking for this question will have the same misconception.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. I was also sneaking in that note to sit right under the question so it's more visible to people who might panic when learning of this issue from your question.

Comment: Cross link at [superuser](https://superuser.com/q/1556852/23156)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to your keys. From the same page that you quoted:

> The better alternatives include:
>
> - The RFC8332 RSA SHA-2 signature algorithms rsa-sha2-256/512. **These
>     algorithms have the advantage of using the same key type as
>     "ssh-rsa" but use the safe SHA-2 hash algorithms.** These have been
>     supported since OpenSSH 7.2 and are already used by default if the
>     client and server support them.

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: Oh, interesting. I thought since [`man ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#HostKeyAlgorithms) listed (e.g.) `rsa-sha2-512` separately from `ssh-rsa` that I'd need to upgrade the keys. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes. Even though they're different algorithms, they use the same keys.

Answer (score 6):

Later OpenSSH release notes are even more explicit that [Joseph's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/226133/56961) is correct. See this [from v8.7](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.7):

> Note that the deactivation of "`ssh-rsa`" signatures does not necessarily
> require cessation of use for RSA keys. In the SSH protocol, keys may be
> capable of signing using multiple algorithms. In particular, "`ssh-rsa`" keys are capable of signing using "`rsa-sha2-256`" (RSA/SHA256),
> "`rsa-sha2-512`" (RSA/SHA512) and "`ssh-rsa`" (RSA/SHA1). Only the last of
> these is being turned off by default.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do as well is create yourself an ECDSA key, as [suggested by OpenSSH 8.6](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.6):

> The better alternatives include:
>
> - […]
> - The RFC5656 ECDSA algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/384/521. These have been supported by OpenSSH since release 5.7.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t ECDSA
```

Copy it over to *authorized_keys* on the target machine:

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub target_machine
```

And bam! You should be able to connect again.

Comment: You're not wrong, but that's the scenario proposed in the question itself.

Comment: @Michael, yep, kind of. However 1. "Generate new key(s?)." looks like a question (thus unsure?). 3. "Rename old key so it does not get picked up automatically" - is not necessary 4. "???" - nothing else to do needed. So it looks to me that my suggestion provides a clean solution to your problem. There's one more thing: your question was ranking on the top when I was searching for the problem and finding out what to do is not very easy. So I figured I'd add the easy and complete solution here so people can quickly solve their problem.

Comment: That makes sense. I should have used just "key(s)" to indicate "maybe plural."

Comment: Thanks for the nice edit @Michael!

Comment: @Michaelcomelately Wow, what an absolute HERO you are!